# React Native support of reverse flex directions

Tags: react-native, flexbox

React Native doesn't support reverse flex direction rules such as `row-reverse` and `column-reverse`. Moreover, it is specifically `oneOf([ 'row', 'column' ])`, despite what is stated in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

My first thought was it hard to implement in native environment, but I found that one can mimic reverse behaviour simply by using `justifyContent: 'center'`. (https://rnplay.org/apps/o5Gr3Q)

My question is, is there any explanation why these rules don't supported by React Native or it is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I haven't tried it but as of 0.29 it seems to be supported. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d43e0db81e86d4d03638cd17034086717fe715a3)

It is not supported at the moment. React Native is using https://github.com/facebook/css-layout#supported-attributes for it's layout and it doesn't support reverse either so it would have to be implemented there.